# How to build and commit multi-query transaction in sqlx?

Tags: mysql, sql, rust, rust-sqlx

In [sqlx](https://docs.rs/sqlx/0.3.5/sqlx/) there's a `Transaction` type which lets you run multiple queries in one transaction.

I'm trying to figure out how to do this, which sadly is not documented, although there is the automatically generated API docs.

My first attempt:

```rust
async fn insert_user() {
    let pool: sqlx::Pool<sqlx::MySql> =
        futures::executor::block_on(crate::db::open_mariadb_pool()).unwrap();
    use sqlx::Acquire;
    let mut conn = pool.acquire().await.unwrap();
    let tx = conn.begin().await.unwrap();
    let insert_query = sqlx::query("INSERT INTO user (email, email_verification_secret, email_verified, password_hash, hourly_rate)
VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?);"
    )
        .bind("text@example.com")
        .bind(false)
        .bind(123)
        .bind("pwhash")
        .bind(20);
    let get_row_query = sqlx::query::<sqlx::MySql>("SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = LAST_INSERT_ID();");
    insert_query.execute(tx);
    get_row_query.execute(tx);
    tx.commit();
}
```

Produces the following error:

```rust
error[E0277]: the trait bound `Transaction<'_, MySql>: Executor<'_>` is not satisfied
  --> src/controller_user.rs:86:26
   |
86 |     insert_query.execute(tx);
   |                          ^^ the trait `Executor<'_>` is not implemented for `Transaction<'_, MySql>`
   |
   = help: the following implementations were found:
             <&'t mut Transaction<'c, MySql> as Executor<'t>>

error[E0277]: the trait bound `Transaction<'_, MySql>: Executor<'_>` is not satisfied
  --> src/controller_user.rs:87:27
   |
87 |     get_row_query.execute(tx);
   |                           ^^ the trait `Executor<'_>` is not implemented for `Transaction<'_, MySql>`
   |
   = help: the following implementations were found:
             <&'t mut Transaction<'c, MySql> as Executor<'t>>
```

I don't really know where to start thinking about this - but am failing to find out from the automatically generated API docs.

Answer (score 14):

There is an example usage in the test `tests/mssql/mssql.rs` in the function `it_can_work_with_transactions`.

The usage appears to be:

```
let mut tx = conn.begin().await?;

sqlx::query("INSERT INTO _sqlx_users_1922 (id) VALUES (@p1)")
    .bind(10_i32)
    .execute(&mut tx)
    .await?;

tx.commit().await?;
```

The only obvious difference between what you are doing and this code is passing a mutable reference, rather than the value as the argument to `execute`.

With that in mind, if we look carefully at your error message, that is exactly what it says. After replacing some bits with ... to leave only the essentials it reads

```
... the trait `Executor<...>` is not implemented for `Transaction<...>`
   |
... the following implementations were found:
             &mut Transaction<...> as Executor<...>
```

Answer (score 12):

To update this answer, version 7.0 now requires this

```
// In 0.7, `Transaction` can no longer implement `Executor` directly,
// so it must be dereferenced to the internal connection type.
.execute(&mut *transaction)
```

https://github.com/launchbadge/sqlx/blob/main/examples/postgres/transaction/src/main.rs